# Getting Images with Google Feed API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, google-feed-api

I'm trying to get images from my wordpress feed (http://dev.emagpress.com/feed) using the google feeds API and don't seem to be able to do it for some reason. My current code is below, minus any attempts i've made at getting images from the feed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me some code that might work?

```
    google.load("feeds", "1");

    function initialize() {
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://dev.emagpress.com/feed");

      feed.load(function(result) {

        if (!result.error) {

          var container = document.getElementById("stories");

          for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {

            var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

            var title = entry.title;
            var pageId = title.toLowerCase().replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()\s]/g,"");
            var link = entry.link;
            var author = entry.author;
            var snippet = entry.contentSnippet;
            var date = entry.publishedDate;
            var content = entry.content;

            console.log(entry);

            var storyOutput = '<div class="storyContainer">';
                    storyOutput += '<a href="#' + pageId + '">' + title + '</a>';
                    storyOutput += '<p>' + snippet + '</p>';
                storyOutput += '</div> <!-- end storyContianer -->';

            $('#stories').append(storyOutput);

            var pageOutput = '<div class="pageContent" data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="' + pageId + '">';
                    pageOutput += '<div data-role="header" class="header">';
                        pageOutput += '<a class="backButton" href="javascript:history.go(-1)" data-transition="slide" data-diraction="reverse" data-icon="back">Back</a>'
                        pageOutput += '<h1>Stories</h1>';
                    pageOutput += '</div>';
                    pageOutput += '<h2 class="storyTitle">' + title + '</h2>';
                    pageOutput += '<div data-role="content" class="mainText">';
                        pageOutput += content;
                    pageOutput += '</div>';
                pageOutput += '</div>';

            $('#insertAfter').after(pageOutput);

          }

        }

      });

    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Comment: So what is the result? Any error?

Comment: My current code works absolutely fine, I would just like to know how to pull images form my feed as well. I'm logging the object that is returned by the google feed request but I can't find my image tags from my feed in there anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `closure` attribute to do that. You can use following structure to get your rss feed.

```
function fetchRss(url) {
    var jsonFeed = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=15&callback=?&q=';
    $.ajax({
        url: jsonFeed + url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'JsonpCallback',
        success: jsonProcessFeed,
    });
}

function jsonpProcessFeed(data) {
    if (data.responseStatus == "200") {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.responseData.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            item = "<li>" + "<a href='" + data.responseData.feed.entries[i].link + "'>" + data.responseData.feed.entries[i].title + "</a>" + "<img src='"+ data.responseData.feed.entries[i].mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url +"'/></li>"
            $('#links').append(item);
        }
    } else {
        alert("An error occurred while fetching rss - " + data.responseDetails);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    fetchRss("http://dev.emagpress.com/feed/");
});
```

Here is a working demo: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/hneGR/2/)

Here is a sample request to api: [API](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=15&callback=JsonpCallback&q=http://dev.emagpress.com/feed/&_=1397744489636)